# Combine a PostgreSQL EXCLUDE range constraint with a UNIQUE constraint

Tags: postgresql, range, constraints

In PostgreSQL, how do you combine an exclusion constraint on a range column with a unique constraint on other, scalar columns. Or to put it another way, how do I ensure that the range overlap check is only done in combination with a unique check on some other columns?

For example, say I have:

```
CREATE TABLE reservation (
    restaurant_id int,
    time_range tsrange
);
```

I want to make sure that for each `restaurant_id`, there are no overlapping `time_range`s.

I know that I can create an exclusive range constraint like this:

```
CREATE TABLE reservation (
    restaurant_id int,
    time_range tsrange EXCLUDE USING gist (time_range WITH &&)
);
```

But how do I make sure that the `time_range` check is scoped by `restaurant_id`?

Comment: Here is a discussion of exactly this topic:  http://thoughts.davisjeff.com/2010/09/25/exclusion-constraints-are-generalized-sql-unique/.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE reservation 
(
    restaurant_id int,
    time_range tsrange,
    EXCLUDE USING gist (restaurant_id with =, time_range WITH &&)
);
```

Note that you need to install the extension `btree_gist` because the GIST index does not have an equality operator by default:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/btree-gist.html